# Condición dentro de un updateOrCreate en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy ingresando registros o actualizandolos en la base de datos.
Estoy usando updateOrCreate en laravel 5.6

Tengo esto que estoy recorriendo con arreglos.

```
foreach (array_reverse($datos->places) as $key){


            $llenar = Lugar::updateOrCreate(
                ['place_id' => $key->place_id],
                ['name' => $key->name,
                'imagep' => $key->image,
                'address' => $key->address,
                'phone' => $key->phone,
                'website' => $key->website,
                'description' => $key->description,
                'lat' => $key->lat,
                'lng' => $key->lng,
                'last_update' => $key->last_update],

                ['imageuno' => $key->images[0]->name,
                'imagedos' => $key->images[1]->name,
                'imagetres' => $key->images[2]->name,
                'imagecuatro' => $key->images[3]->name]
        );
```

}

Resulta que cuando recorro el arreglo Images que estan enumerado en 4 lineas  imageuno, imagedos, imagetres, imagecuatro 
Aveces alguno de los images No existe (la posicion no existe y laravel me devuelve "Undefined offset: X posicion)  Lo que se me ocurre es poner una condicion

```
if (!empty($key->images[0]->name)) {
                    'imageuno' => $key->images[0]->name,
                }else{
                    //si esta vacio no hace nada
                }
```

Para cada uno de ellos.

Pero el problema es que no se meter la condición dentro del (UpdateOrCreate de laravel).

O alguna manera de detectar si la posición del arreglo existe y excluirlo antes de meterlo al updateorCreate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo amigos, la solucion la encontre asi.

Lo que hice fue colocar condiciones arriba. (yo lo que quería era meterlas dentro del updateorcreate).

Si la posición existe se guarda en la variable Imageadd1 y sucesivamente con cada una de ellas.

Si no existe se le asigna a la variable el valor VACÍA.  esto para asumir la posición y no dejar el campo libre porque era tomado por datos de la posición anterior siguiendo el patrón natural del llenado.

a la final quedo asi

```
                if (!empty($key->images[0]->name)) {
                    $imageadd1 = $key->images[0]->name;
                }else{
                    $imageadd1 = 'vacio';
                }
                if (!empty($key->images[1]->name)) {
                    $imageadd2 = $key->images[1]->name;
                }else{
                    $imageadd2 = 'vacio';
                }
                if (!empty($key->images[2]->name)) {
                    $imageadd3 = $key->images[2]->name;
                }else{
                   $imageadd3 = 'vacio';
                }
                if (!empty($key->images[3]->name)) {
                    $imageadd4 = $key->images[3]->name;
                }else{
                    $imageadd4 = 'vacio';
                }


            $llenar = Lugar::updateOrCreate(

                ['place_id' => $key->place_id],
                ['name' => $key->name,
                'imagep' => $key->image,
                'address' => $key->address,
                'phone' => $key->phone,
                'website' => $key->website,
                'description' => $key->description,
                'lat' => $key->lat,
                'lng' => $key->lng,
                'last_update' => $key->last_update,

                'imageuno' => $imageadd1,
                'imagedos' => $imageadd2,
                'imagetres' => $imageadd3,
                'imagecuatro' => $imageadd4]


        );
```

Y listo. eso lo mandaba a la db con UpdateOrCreate !

Answer (score 0):

Si **$key->images** es un array deberías acceder a sus datos mediante corchetes **$key->images[0]['name']** y no como una colección.

Comment: No funciona estimado, laravel me devuelve  "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Answer (score 0):

Hoy (escuchando los laracasts de laravel 5.4) he aprendido que existe desde php4 la funcion compact().

$imageuno = $key->images[0]->name;
$imagedos = $key->images[1]->name;
$imagetres = $key->images[2]->name;

$a=compact('imageuno','imagedos','imagetres','imagecuatro')

Esto te devuelve 
['imageuno'=>$key->images[0]->name, ...] y como $imagecuatro no existe no lo asigna.

Quizás te de una idea ...